# I want to clear a text box when i click on my drop down list

Tags: html, onfocus

This is my code for my drop down list which works

```
<select id="PublisherID" name="$publisher" onfocus="if(this.id=='PublisherID') if(this.value='value')
```

This is my code for my text box which also works

```
 <input id="Title" name="k" value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value=='Search...') this.value='';
```

I want to be able to click on my drop down list and it clears whats in the text box.

Can anyone help please

Comment: I assume this is JavaScript that you are using?

Comment: Please add that information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This how you can achieve it.

Jquery:

```
//For example on change of list
$('#list').change(function(){
    alert('list changed : clear text');
    //Set what value you want for text field');
    $('#text').val('Search...');
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id='list'>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text" value="Search..."/>
```

Here is a demo : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bhimubgm/mj5Cm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="cleartextbox()">
    <option value="libero">libero</option>
    <option value="Ram">Ram</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function cleartextbox() {
        document.getElementById("mark").value = "";
    }
</script>

<label>
    <span>Mark</span>
    <input  type="text" name="mark" id="mark" >
</label>
```